# automatic upload from onedrive to my computer

Tags: onedrive

I used to automatically get my photos taken with my phone uploaded on onedrive and on my onedrive folder in my computer. Now I can not. Does anyone know how to get that function back?

Comment: What phone do you have? What version of Windows Phone or Windows 10 Mobile is it running? Did you change any settings on your phone or computer right before the problem started? Do the pictures make it to OneDrive or are they stuck on your phone? Do you have enough free space on OneDrive?

Comment: Also, do the photos show up when logging in to onedrive via a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are logged in.
Enough storage left.
Good Internet connectivity.
If all above are done then Goto Setting in Photos , Scroll Down you will find Option - "Manage OneDrive upload Settings" and turn the camera upload to ON.  (This is in respect to Win 10, in other versions too you'll find similar options )